# grep or awk, how to convert data to multiple columns in csv file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have following log file data

```
2/1/1/2/tasdfn.c:

LOG:
        backslash-newline should be deleted before tokenizing
    No diagnostics line
--
2/1/1/2/tlsdf.c:

LOG:
+++ stderr ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
tlsdf.c:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wchar_t'
--
2/2/4/1/tasdf.gen(0):

LOG:
    511 external identifiers in one source file
    Compilation failed ungracefully
--
2/2/4/1/tiasdf.gen(0):

LOG:
    8 nesting levels of #include files
    Compilation failed ungracefully
--
```

And wanted to covert above data to following: where `coulmn1` should `testname`(i.e 2/1/1/2/testname.c) and `coulmn2` should `LOG` details:

expected Output in csv file:

```
2/1/1/2/tasdfn.c:           LOG:
                            backslash-newline should be deleted before tokenizing
                            No diagnostics line


2/1/1/2/tlsdf.c:            LOG:
                            +++ stderr ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                            tlsdf.c:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 't'



2/2/4/1/tasdf.gen(0):       LOG:
                            511 external identifiers in one source file
                            Compilation failed ungracefully
```

Not able to get the desired output from `grep` and `awk`. 
Using grep i can get testname i.e and Log details as separate output

```
cat test.log | grep -Ea '*.c:$|*.gen\([0-9]\):' //prints testname
cat test.log | grep -Ea '*.c:$|*.gen\([0-9]\):' -A4 //prints testname with Log details
```

how to get data in mentioned format where .csv file as output??

Comment: is the second log message correct? I seem to be missing a space after the '>'

Comment: Your "expected output in csv file" sample isn't in CSV format...

Answer (score 0):

*After Update:*

```
awk '/^--/{printf "\n\n"; f=0; next }
     !f { printf "%-29s%s\n", $0, "LOG:"; f=1; next}
     /^$/{next}
     /LOG:/{next}
     {sub(/ */,""); printf "%-29s%s\n", "", $0}' file
```

---

This comes close to what you want, but I had to add an extra space in you second log message to make it work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n> -- *\n *"; FS="  +" }
     { gsub(/\n>|LOG:/,"") }
     { sub(/^ /,"",$1); sub(/:*$/,":",$1); printf "%-29s%s\n",$1,"LOG:"}
     { for(i=2;i<=NF; ++i) printf "%-29s%s\n","",$i; printf "\n\n" }' file
```

The idea is to have awk define records which are split by `\n> -- *\n *` and fields which are split by multiple spaces (that is why I needed to add an extra space after the `+++++++++++...`).

**output:**

```
2/1/1/2/tasdfn.c:            LOG:
                             backslash-newline should be deleted before tokenizing
                             No diagnostics line


2/1/1/2/tlsdf.c:             LOG:
                             +++ stderr ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                             tlsdf.c:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 't'


2/2/4/1/tasdf.gen(0):        LOG:
                             511 external identifiers in one source file
                             Compilation failed ungracefully


2/2/4/1/tiasdf.gen(0):       LOG:
                             8 nesting levels of #include files
                             Compilation failed ungracefully --
```

**original input:**

```
> 2/1/1/2/tasdfn.c:
> 
> LOG:      backslash-newline should be deleted before tokenizing   No
> diagnostics line
> -- 
>2/1/1/2/tlsdf.c:
> 
> LOG:
> +++ stderr 
>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
>tlsdf.c:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 't'
> --
> 2/2/4/1/tasdf.gen(0):
> 
> LOG:  511 external identifiers in one source file     Compilation failed
> ungracefully
> -- 
>2/2/4/1/tiasdf.gen(0)::
> 
> LOG:  8 nesting levels of #include files  Compilation failed
> ungracefully
> --
```

Comment: I have corrected the second long message (there was a typo error while pasting). but with your command not able to generate the output (it dumps everything to single column) to .csv file where `column1` should contain `testname` and column2 should contain `LOG:` details associated with it.

Comment: @code_seeker it makes sense it did not work. The format is completely different as there are no '>' in the beginning of the lines.